# Is there an improvement for the Schur-Horn inequalities for positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, inequalities, random-matrices, semidefinite-programming

By the Schur-Horn inequality I am thinking of the statement that for any Hermitian matrix $H$ its diagonal n-tuple $(H_{11},H_{22},..,H_{nn})$ for any choice of basis lies in the convex hull of the $n!$ permutations of its eigenvalue n-tuple.

Or any further improvement if one assumes not just the p.s.d structure but also that, $H_{ii} = \sum_{j \neq i} H_{ij}$?

Comment: For the first one, can't you just add a multiple of the identity to embed the usual problem into the semidefinite one, i.e. they're the same level of difficulty?

Comment: @AllenKnutson I am not getting you - are you saying that any semi-definite matrix is also Hermitian and decomposable in some particular way such that the Schur-Horn can be used on the parts individually? Can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @AllenKnutson In the Schur-Horn inequalities can the diagonal entries be defined in any basis? (..because I am a bit confused by the statement here in equation 9 - http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/ - where Terence Tao seems to want to choose the "standard basis"..)

Comment: By "improvement", I assumed that the question was "if we impose more conditions, do we get a better result?" i.e. that the matrices were still Hermitian. Then my dumb trick says "no, we don't". As to the second comment: any orthonormal basis will work, giving you the same permutahedron.

Comment: @AllenKnutson About my second comment - what I mean is this - if $A$ is any Hermitian matrix then can I always say that $ (min-eigenvalue) \leq A_{ii} \leq (max-eigenvalue)$ ? (for any choice of basis) ?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, the answer is "_Very_ obviously yes," enough so that I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @AllenKnutson Yes :P But this is not a trivial statement - right? The inequality for $A_{ii}$ that I wrote above comes because of the Schur-Horn inequality - right?

Comment: Let  $\vec v = \sum_j c_j \vec e_j$, where $\vec v$ is the $i$th vector in your orthonormal basis, and the $(e_j)$ are an orthonormal eigenbasis (with eigenvalues $(\lambda_i))$, and $\sum_i |c_i|^2=1$. Then $A_{ii} = \langle \vec v,A \vec v\rangle = \sum_i |c_i|^2 \lambda_i \in [\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$. It's a little weird to credit Schur and Horn with this.

Comment: @AllenKnutson Okay - but does Schur-Horn say anything stronger about $A_{ii}$ than this? Can it be constrained any further than $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$? (...for something I was thinking of I have been wondering if there is a constrain which is $O(1/dim(A))$...does something like this exist?..)

Comment: especially if p.s.d nature is assumed..

Comment: Consider the case $A$ real diagonal, and realize, "No."

Comment: @AllenKnutson If $A$ is a $\pm 1$ signed graph Laplacian or an adjacency matrix ?

Comment: If your matrix is special then it's unlikely that Schur-Horn gives the best possible results.

Comment: @AllenKnutson hmmm..so I asked a separate question about that - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188172/are-there-any-special-properties-of-graph-eigenvalues-of-perfect-matchings